# Create Bitmap from Collection of BitmapSources

Tags: c#

I would like to create the Bitmap from BitmapSource Collection  and Each source source should be one frame.

I wrote the following code

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
BitmapEncoder enCoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();

foreach (BitmapSource source in BitmapSources)
    enCoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
enCoder.Save(memStream);
_Bitmap = new DrawingCtrl.Bitmap(memStream);

DrawingCtrl.ImageAnimator.Animate(_Bitmap, OnFrameChanged);
```

and

```
private void OnFrameChangedInMainThread()
{
    DrawingCtrl.ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames(_Bitmap);
    Source = GetBitmapSource(_Bitmap);
    InvalidateVisual();
}
```

But it shows `"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."`. Could anyone help me?

Comment: As a general rule, the `TargetInvocationException` (which says “Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation”) is only a wrapper exception. If you catch this exception and look at the `InnerException` property on the exception object, it contains the *actual* exception. Of course, in some cases you might have several layers of this wrapping, so use a while loop to get at the innermost exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know about BitmapSources in WPF, but I notice an error in how you use `MemoryStream`, so maybe this is the issue:

```
enCoder.Save(memStream);
```

This will write the content to the memory stream and leave the stream pointer at the end.

```
_Bitmap = new DrawingCtrl.Bitmap(memStream);
```

This will then try to read the bitmap from the stream, starting at the *end* of the stream. Of course that can’t work. Try adding a seek in between:

```
enCoder.Save(memStream);
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
_Bitmap = new DrawingCtrl.Bitmap(memStream);
```

Comment: I tried your answer.But after creating bitmap again it shows only one frame. but i need the collection of frames.